# Attempting full screen mode when using a Scorm Cloud (a learning management system)

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, scorm

I'm attempting to get a course I developed to go full screen when it's launched from Scorm Cloud (a learning management system). I managed to get full screen when launched directly from the LMS with this code from W3:

```
 var html = document.querySelector('html');
        console.log(html)
        if (html.requestFullscreen) {
            html.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (html.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
            html.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (html.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
            html.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (html.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
            html.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
```

However, when I send an invitation to take the course through email. The course doesn't launch full screen. Can you please tell me why that is?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen):

> Note: This method must be called while responding to a user interaction or a device orientation change; otherwise it will fail.

I assume you somehow fullfilled that requirement in the first case, and not in the second.

Comment: Oh, okay. I think I get it now. I put in the error catch and it gave me API can only be initiated by a user gesture. I'm assuming when launched from the LMS the user gesture is launching the course button, but when launched from an invitation url, there is no user gesture, per say?

Comment: @SamanthaLowe yeah, that sounds as if that could be it. Maybe add a "launch" button to the invitation page too?